# What operators can be used to ceil an integer division?

Tags: c, operators

I have this code below which is suppose to generate the output of 11 dwarfs for input of 10 for dwarf height and values of 101, 102, 103, 104,105, 106, 107, 108, 109 as well as 110 for giant height then change to output of 12 dwarfs for values of giant height of 111-120 and so forth when the height of dwarf again is 10. Both 'n' and 's' have essentially the same solution: proper output of dwarfs for values of 101 - 109 but not correct output (should be 11, but gives 10) for the value of 110. What operators can be used to help with this. I am working on my operator usage and would strongly prefer not to use any conditional statements or if-then.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int g, d, n, s;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter the heights of giant and drwafs: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &g, &d);
        
        n = g % d +  (g/d) + (-g % d + 1) - (g%d + 1)/10;
        s = g / d + 1;
        printf("%d",s);
        
        printf("it takes %d dwarfs to be "
               "greater than or equal to giant.\n\n", s );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ceiling of integer division:

```
unsigned int dividend, divisor, c;
/* dividend != 0 && divisor != 0 */
c = 1 + ((dividend - 1) / divisor);
```

Your program would then look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int giant, dwarf, c;

    printf("Height of giant: ");
    scanf("%u", &giant);
    printf("Height of dwarf: ");
    scanf("%u", &dwarf);

    /* the heights can't be 0 */
    if (giant == 0 || dwarf == 0) {
        printf("The heights need to be greater than 0.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* ceil giant divided by dwarf */
    c = 1 + ((giant - 1) / dwarf);

    printf("It takes %u dwarfs to be as high "
           "or higher than a giant.\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The formula is correct but problem with this is that you will overflow if giant + dwarf -1 is above INT_MAX

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL That is very unlikely, as the numbers he is dealing with seem to be relatively small, but I have updated my answer anyways.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Thanks, I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NOT operator, if you have a remainder it will add 1, if you have no remainder it will just be the result of your division:

```c
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int g, d, s;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter the heights of giant and drwafs: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &g, &d);
        if (d <= 0 || g <= 0) // what if your user use 0 for the size of dwarf? ouch...
            continue
        s = g / d + !!(g % d);
        printf("%d",s);
        
        printf("it takes %d dwarfs to be "
               "greater than or equal to giant.\n\n", s );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

NB: This solution works with giant = INT_MAX